# linux problem after yum update

Tags: rhel

I have a problem after `yum update`.

> command stay on Updating : ksh-20120801-137.0.1.el7.x86_64 
>   and terminal hang after df -h.

I ran `strace df -h and log show`:

```
stat("/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) 
= 0
stat("/sys/fs/cgroup/memory", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) 
= 0
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/sys/fs/selinux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc",
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this upgrading old systems.  I think it is a bug in an old version of systemd.  The best way to get your 'yum update' to finish cleanly is to run

```
ps auxw | grep systemd
```

and find the '/bin/systemctl try-restart systemd-binfmt.service' process and kill it.

I should also add the 'df' will hang when your system is in this state.